# How to use aggregate function in update in SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, sql-update

**I Tried as shown below:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
ID INT,
EmpID INT,
AMOUNT INT
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1,1,10)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2,1,5)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(3,2,6)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(4,3,8)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(5,3,10)
.
.
.

SELECT * FROM #TEMP

ID EmpID    AMOUNT
1   1       10
2   1       5
3   2       6
4   3       8
5   4       10  

UPDATE #TEMP
SET AMOUNT = SUM(AMOUNT) - 11
Where EmpID = 1
```

**Expected Output:**
    Table consists of employeeID's along with amount assigned to Employee I need to subtract amount from amount filed depending on employee usage. Amount "10" should be deducted from ID = 1 and amount "1" should be deducted from ID = 2.

**Amount:** Credits available for that particular employee depending on date.

So i need to reduce credits from table depending on condition first i need to subtract from old credits. In my condition i need to collect 11 rupees from empID = 1 so first i need to collect **10** rupee from ID=1 and **1** rupee from the next credit i.e ID=2. For this reason in my expected output for ID=1 the value is **0** and final output should be like

```
ID EmpID    AMOUNT
1   1       0
2   1       4
3   2       6
4   3       8
5   4       10
```

Need help to update records. Check error in my update statement.

Comment: For `ID = 1` why it is 0?

Comment: I should deduct amount in order by ID so first i need to deduct in ID = 1 depending on deduction amount. @RahulTripathi

Comment: Why amount 10 deducted by 10 and amount 2 deducted by 1 why?

Comment: @Dineshalla:- That still doesn't make it clear, `SUM(AMOUNT)` for `ID =1` will be `10` and `10-11` would be `-1`. Why it is `0`?

Comment: Your question says SQL Server 2012 and tagged as 2008. Which is correct?

Comment: We've get what you want , but i we know know if where deducted values came from.. why 10 ? and why 1 ? , where is 10 and 1 came from ?  , is that static number you wanted to deduct or there are columns for that numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @Deduct int = -11, 
@CurrentDeduct int = 0 /*this represent the deduct per row */
update #TEMP 
        set   @CurrentDeduct = case when abs(@Deduct) >= AMOUNT then Amount else abs(@Deduct) end 
             , @Deduct = @Deduct + @CurrentDeduct
            ,AMOUNT = AMOUNT - @CurrentDeduct
    where EmpID= 1
```

Comment: If i change value of @sum = -16 then also it is updating to 0 but it is false condition. Can you update your query.

Comment: @Dineshalla, kindly send the input and the expected output, i don't know what is the problem?

Comment: @Dineshalla, i simplified the code by using two variables.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the following: subtract amounts from `11` while remainder is positive. If this is true, here is a solution with recursive `cte`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( id INT, amount INT )

INSERT  INTO @t VALUES  
( 1, 10 ),
( 2, 5 ),
( 3, 3 ),
( 4, 2 );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * , 17 - amount AS remainder
               FROM     @t
               WHERE    id = 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   t.* , c.remainder - t.amount AS remainder
               FROM     @t t
                        CROSS JOIN cte c
               WHERE    t.id = c.id + 1 AND c.remainder > 0
             )
    UPDATE  t
    SET     amount = CASE WHEN c.remainder > 0 THEN 0
                          ELSE -remainder
                     END
    FROM    @t t
            JOIN cte c ON c.id = t.id

SELECT  * FROM    @t
```

Output:

```
id  amount
1   0
2   0
3   1
4   2
```

Here I use `17` as start remainder.

If you use `sql server 2012+` then you can do it like:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        17 - SUM(amount) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS remainder
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  id ,
            CASE WHEN remainder >= 0 THEN 0
                 WHEN remainder < 0
                      AND LAG(remainder) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) >= 0
                 THEN -remainder
                 ELSE amount
            END
    FROM    cte
```

Comment: For `id=2`, OP needs `amount=4`. Your answer returning `0`?

Comment: @Kaf he use 17 as start.

Answer (score 0):

First you should get a cumulative sum on amount:

```
select 
  id, 
  amount,
  sum(amount) over (order by id) running_sum 
from #TEMP;
```

From here we should put 0 on rows before running_sum exceeds the value 11. Update the row where the running sum exceeds 11 and do nothing to rows after precedent row.

```
select 
id,
amount
running_sum,
min(case when running_sum > 11 then id end) over () as decide
from (

    select 
      id, 
      amount,
      sum(amount) over (order by id) running_sum 
    from #TEMP

);
```

From here we can do the update:

```
merge into #TEMP t
using (    
    select 
      id,
      amount
      running_sum,
      min(case when running_sum > 11 then id end) over () as decide
    from (
        select 
          id, 
          amount,
          sum(amount) over (order by id) running_sum 
        from #TEMP
        )
    )a  on a.id=t.id
when matched then update set 
  t.amount = case when a.id = a.decide then a.running_sum - 11
                  when a.id < a.decide then 0
                  else a.amount 
             end;
```

See an [SQLDFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/57637b/4)

Comment: Showing error as Incorrect syntax near 'order'. @FlorinGhita

Comment: This is an oracle solution? The question is about SQL Server

Comment: @JamesZ no, this should work also on sqlserver or with small modifications. I used oracle on sqlfiddle because it gives "better" errors :)